# Problem with Grid fields?

Tags: 2.7.0, grid

I have this kind of code structure. `foo` and `bar` are both Grid fields.

```
{if "{foo:total_rows}" > 0 OR "{bar:total_rows}" > 0}
  {if "{foo:total_rows}" > 0}
       {foo}
          {foo:a}
          {foo:b}
          {foo:c}
       {/foo}
  {/if}
{/if}
```

The problem is that {foo:a},{foo:b} and {foo:c} is not outputting anything.

However, when I do this

```
{if "{foo:total_rows}" > 0 OR "{bar:total_rows}" > 0}

   {foo}
      {foo:a}
      {foo:b}
      {foo:c}
   {/foo}

   {if "{foo:total_rows}" > 0}
        {foo}
           {foo:a}
           {foo:b}
           {foo:c}
        {/foo}
    {/if}
{/if}
```

I get

```
{foo}{/foo}abc
```

a, b, and c are the contents of {foo:a},{foo:b} and {foo:c} respectively.

What is the problem here? Is this a parse order issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks odd that {foo} is not recognised at first.

Have you tried modifying

```
{if "{foo:total_rows}" > 0}
```

It looks like you could be comparing a string to a number.  What does

```
{if {foo:total_rows} > 0}
```

give you?

Also, what happens if you test removing the outer if?

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to a bug that causes [PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit) when parsing tag pairs. Essentially the regular expression thats used to find chunks of the template by pairing opening and closing tags doesn't perform efficiently enough in some cases. Here is the [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21004/regex-catastrophic-backtracking-in-get_pair_field).

The bug report contains a work around that may work for you. In `system/expressionengine/libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php` change line `1852` (this line number is from the 2.9.2 codebase, so it may differ, should be within the `get_pair_field` function) to:

```
if (preg_match("/".LD."{$field_name}((?::[^\s}]+)?)(\s.*?)?".RD."(.*?)".LD.'\/'."{$field_name}\\1".RD."/s", $tagdata, $matches, 0, $offset))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar strangeness with conditionals and Grid fields. See [Some crazy results from an "OR" conditional with Grid type](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41788/some-crazy-results-from-an-or-conditional-with-grid-type)